# When to proceed to Silverglen?

Tags: divinity-original-sin

So as I was going through the storyline quests, I found myself in Cyseal's area facing

> Braccus Rex and a cohort of previous bosses from the same area.

I couldn't really handle it at Lv 8 so I decided to explore more and ended up in Silverglen. The story now seems to continue in a different direction which is bizarre since the ancient evil is still stomping around in the basement; do I go deal with that first or do I continue with multitude of quests in Silverglen?

Comment: Silverglen is a harder area.  Have you done everything in act1 already?

Comment: When does act one end exactly?

Comment: Act 1 is the Cyseal map.  Silverglen is the act 2 map, hunter's edge is the act 3 map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go there as soon as you can fight your way through the monsters guarding the road. There is no specific order in which quests or areas must be completed, although there is a level grading and in Silverglen things will quickly get harder than they were back in Cyseal.

If you want to level up a bit more to be able to cope with a certain fight, do make sure you've explored everything on the Cyseal map thoroughly.

> Make sure you didn't miss Black Cove, which is out the west gate from Cyseal harbour.